# Bootstrap .NET MAUI project with specific components

Tags: project, maui

Every time I am starting a new .NET MAUI project, I basically do the same steps repeatedly:

- Create new MAUI app
- Add Fontawesome font and create a styles dictionary to hold the unicode - keyword pairs
- Add multilanguage support (Nuget package) and resx files to hold translations
- Add test project for unit tests (xunit)

... and maybe more in future.

Is there a way how to automate that? How do you do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're running on Windows, you could use Matt Lacey's [MAUI App Accelerator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MattLaceyLtd.MauiAppAccelerator), which let's you create a templated MAUI app using a wizard-like Visual Studio extension.

You could also create your own custom [project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/creating-custom-project-and-item-templates?view=vs-2022) for your MAUI apps in Visual Studio which could bootstrap all the things you would like to use frequently.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - right now I am on a Mac, and it seems, that even the project templates can only be used in VS for Windows. But it may be the case, that I'll be working on Windows in the future and I'll keep your suggestions in mind. Thanks!

Comment: You could use a virtual machine with a lightweight installation of Windows and VS to create your solutions and repositories :D